# JSON Jquery Array type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geonames

I have a basic question on JSON Jquery, and it seams I am sort of stuck some at a point of extracting array objects. My Code below is in javascript, and I just wanted some clarifications as what I might be doing wrong here.

```
<?php  
$nor = $_SESSION["north"];
$sou =  $_SESSION["south"];
$eas =  $_SESSION["east"];
$wes = $_SESSION["west"];

session_destroy();

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <title>jQuery JSON test</title>  
  </head>  

  <body>  


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    var north = "<?php echo $nor ?>";
        var south = "<?php echo $sou ?>"; 
        var east = "<?php echo $eas ?>";
        var west = "<?php echo $wes ?>";

        document.write(north,south,east,west);


    $(document).ready(function(){

        alert("begin loop");
        $.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=' + north + ' &south=' + south + '&east=' + east + '&west=' + west +'&callback=?',
        function(data){
            alert(data.earthquakes);
    });
})

    </script>  

  </body>  
</html>
```

So when I use alert(data.earthquakes); I get undefined operation, which is fine but I know here I am getting a response back. However the architecture of the JSON is as following:

```
{"earthquakes": [
     {"eqid":"2007hear","magnitude":8.4,"lng":101.3815,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-09-12 09:10:26","depth":30,"lat":-4.5172},
     {"eqid":"2007aqbk","magnitude":8,"lng":156.9567,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-04-01 18:39:56","depth":10,"lat":-8.4528},
     {"eqid":"2007hec6","magnitude":7.8,"lng":100.9638,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-09-12 21:49:01","depth":10,"lat":-2.5265}
]}
```

So I have tried different ways of extracting information such as `alert(data.earthquakes[1].eqid);` and `alert(data.earthquakes.eqid[1]);`, however I am not getting the dedicated array as wanted.

Could someone direct me as

1. how to get the desired architecture result appropriately and
2. if I want to use array and for loop to extract all the elements into local array,

how to do that?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in Chrome (or whatever) and see what type of thing shows up. It's possible that your JSON is just being served incorrectly.

Comment: *"I know here I am getting a response back"* How did you make this determination?

Comment: Is the sample JSON string only an example or is this the *real* response you got?

Comment: Nevermind, the negative operator is valid without double-quotes. http://www.JSON.org/

Comment: *I am not getting the dedicated array as wanted*... what *are* you getting?

Comment: @Marcel: Thanks for the heads up...I was aware of this. My business partner and I are shutting down the site. Changed my home site to the current one (which has known issues too lol)

Comment: The documentation for that geonames stuff says that every API call needs a "username" parameter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON object is defined as follows:

```
var jsonData = {"earthquakes": [
         {"eqid":"2007hear","magnitude":8.4,"lng":101.3815,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-09-12 09:10:26","depth":30,"lat":-4.5172},
         {"eqid":"2007aqbk","magnitude":8,"lng":156.9567,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-04-01 18:39:56","depth":10,"lat":-8.4528},
         {"eqid":"2007hec6","magnitude":7.8,"lng":100.9638,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-09-12 21:49:01","depth":10,"lat":-2.5265}
    ]};
```

Try this:

```
var myData = eval('(' + jsonData + ')');
var firstElement = myData.earthquakes[0];
```

This is a good point of reference:  http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: 1. That's not a JSON object, but a string-representation of a JavaScript object, conform the JSON spec. 2. Bluntly doing `eval` forms a huge security issue. 3. [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) takes care of this anyway.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: It is a normal JavaScript object (if you refer to `jsonData`).

Comment: @Felix: Oops, of course you're right; I had the original JSON string of the question in my head.

Comment: Isn't that what JSON ultimately is?  A string-representation of a JavaScript data object?  .... JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: @Kon: JSON is a *subset* of the object literal notation, so yes, they look similar, but you cannot label them interchangeably. A JavaScript object is a JS object and JSON is JSON. JSON is a data exchange format. You could not just pass the data contained in `jsonData` to another programming language, because it *is not* JSON. You'd first have to convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify` (so it cannot be JSON beforehand). Have a look at: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Hello Everyone, I got the problem where it was, and have resolved it.